# c++/CLI wrapper for pointer member - c++ singleton instance

Tags: c++, singleton, c++-cli, wrapper

I am completing my c++/CLI wrapper for the following native c++ class:

```
#ifndef __TV3DENGINE_H__
#define __TV3DENGINE_H__
#pragma once

#include "TV3DMoteur.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Area.h"
#include <vcclr.h>

class Engine3D
{
public:
     CLTV3DMoteur* clTV3D;
     CLInput* clInput;
     CLArea* clArea;
     CLGlobalVar * clGlobalVar;

     Engine3D();
     ~Engine3D();

     void Setup(HWND TVScreenHWND, string PathString);
     void UpdateLoop();
     void Cleanup();
     bool AppStillIdle();

     CLTV3DMoteur* GetTV3D();
     CLInput* GetInput();
     CLArea* GetArea();
     CLGlobalVar * GetGlobalVar();
};
#endif
```

The actual constructor for Engine3D is :

```
Engine3D::Engine3D()
{
    clTV3D = CLTV3DMoteur::getInstance();
    clInput = CLInput::getInstance();
    clArea = CLArea::getInstance();
    clGlobalVar = CLGlobalVar::getInstance();
}
```

Here is the actual wrapper:

```
#ifndef __WRAPPER_H__
#define __WRAPPER_H__
#pragma once
#include "TV3DEngine.h"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>


public ref class Engine3DWrapper {
    Engine3D* m_nativeClass;

public:
    Engine3DWrapper() { m_nativeClass = new Engine3D(); }
    ~Engine3DWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
    void Setup(System::IntPtr tvscreen, System::String^ AppPath) {
        System::String^ managedPath = AppPath;
        m_nativeClass->Setup((HWND)tvscreen.ToInt32(), msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managedPath));
    }
    void UpdateLoop() {
        m_nativeClass->UpdateLoop();
    }
    void Cleanup() {
        m_nativeClass->Cleanup();
    }
    bool AppStillIdle() {
        return(m_nativeClass->AppStillIdle());
    }

protected:
    !Engine3DWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
};
#endif
```

My question is how can I modifiy my Wrapper so I can have access to, exemple,  Engine3DWrapper->clGlobalVar->BLABLABLA() where BLABLABLA would be all the different methods defined in the CLGlobalVar c++singleton?

I tried via this technique :

```
 property String ^Name
  {
    String ^get()
    {
      return gcnew String(_stu->getName());
    }
  }
```

but that seems not possible since I need not to return a defined type.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not make a new member function within `Engine3DWrapper` that returns `m_nativeClass->GetGlobalVar()`?  (Or you could create a new member variable called `clGlobalVar` within `Engine3DWrapper` that stores the value of `GetGlobalVar()` after initialization.)

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle this, all nasty because of the basic fact that you are handing things to different models. One way is a "Handle" type class, which will be another wrapper that does not delete the child class. Another would be to move the C++ to a more garbage collected ownership (use shared pointers).

Comment: @Rufflewind : That was my first approach but I blocked at what type should I use to create the new member variable...

Comment: @IdeaHat: Thanks, I'll research this.

Comment: @Windrider: would `CLGlobalVar * m_globalVar` not work?  (I'm not familiar with the restrictions in managed classes.)

Comment: @Rufflewind: Thanks, it actually worked! I thought I could not use an unmanaged type to declare a variable in a managed class.

Application crashes at closing though so could it be related?  I'll dig this some more.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
Here is the corrected Wrapper following Rufflewind suggestion:

```
#ifndef __WRAPPER_H__
#define __WRAPPER_H__
#pragma once
#include "TV3DEngine.h"
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>


public ref class Engine3DWrapper {
    Engine3D* m_nativeClass;

public:
    Engine3DWrapper(System::IntPtr tvscreen, System::String^ AppPath)
    { 
        m_nativeClass = new Engine3D((HWND)tvscreen.ToInt32(), msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(AppPath));
        m_TV3D = m_nativeClass->GetTV3D();
        m_Input = m_nativeClass->GetInput();
        m_Area = m_nativeClass->GetArea();
        m_GlobalVar = m_nativeClass->GetGlobalVar();
    }
    ~Engine3DWrapper() { 
        delete m_nativeClass; 
    }
    void UpdateLoop() {
        m_nativeClass->UpdateLoop();
    }
    void Cleanup() {
        m_nativeClass->Cleanup();
    }
    bool AppStillIdle() {
        return(m_nativeClass->AppStillIdle());
    }

    CLTV3DMoteur* m_TV3D;
    CLInput* m_Input;
    CLArea* m_Area;
    CLGlobalVar* m_GlobalVar;

protected:
    !Engine3DWrapper() { delete m_nativeClass; }
};
#endif
```

using simple Get Method in the native class:

```
CLGlobalVar *Engine3D::GetGlobalVar()
{
    clGlobalVar = CLGlobalVar::getInstance();
    return(clGlobalVar);
}
```

Thanks for you help!